# Unique HTML IDs on a page

Tags: css, label, unique

I often had the following on a form:

```
input#userid{
    left : 10px;
    top:130px;
    width : 180px;
}

label#userid{
    left : 10px;
    top:156px;
}
```

I am aware that ids on a page should be unique and have always considered the above to be unique.  Now however I am reading about "label for" and wonder if my IDs are truly unique in the spirit of HTML.

Comment: There should be no more than one node with a given ID in an HTML document. Is this your question?

Comment: This question doesn't contain any actual HTML.  There is nothing wrong with having those two rules in a CSS style sheet.  But, both rules should not apply to a single HTML document.

Comment: can u please elaborate your question...? are you using twitter bootstrap or else.? if so please add that specific tag to your question.

Comment: This won't serve the purpose of label. There will be a conflict between ids as which component needs to get focus on clicking label as there are 2 elements with same id.

Comment: No, I'm not using twitter.  I generally label an input field using the same id.  I assumed that prefacing the # with an element would make the ids uniqe.  I now understand that it does not.

Comment: I guess I would follow on then and ask what value is there is label#userid rather than just #userid?

Answer (score 0):

In the browser world, assuming you have the two elements with the same ID in your HTML, it probably will work. However, that HTML will not validate, could break various types of HTML processors, and might work or not work depending on the browser and/or the doctype. See also [unique id value in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505104/unique-id-value-in-html).

Answer (score 0):

Nope. IDs should be unique in a document, across all elements. Yes, you can get away with non-unique IDs, but it's not a good idea.

For a rule of thumb, if you find yourself wanting to use the same ID on two elements, you should consider using a class instead. In the specific example above, you might give the input field `userid` as both a class and an ID, and only use it as the class for the label.

Or, you could use the CSS Attribute Selector to target the label in your CSS:

```
input#userid{
  left: 10px;
  top 130px;
  width: 180px;
}

label[for="userid"]{
  left: 10px;
  top: 156px;
}
```

...assuming you assigned the `for` attribute on the label.

Comment: A bit more thought and I'm confused again.  I need to use IDs so that I can absolutely position elements so using a class won't help.

So, if I have a text box that I want to label, then the correct way is

    #inputlname{...}
and
    #labellname{...}


So why would one ever use label#lname as a css descriptor?  Why not always #labellname?

Comment: You can still use a class to target it for absolute positioning, but I just updated my answer with a better way; using the attribute selector.